# ValueError: script argument must be unicode. - Python3.5, SQLite3

Tags: python, unicode, sqlite

I'm writing following python script:

```py
import sqlite3
import sys

if len(sys.argv) < 2:
    print("Error: You must supply at least SQL script.")
    print("Usage: %s table.db ./sql-dump.sql" % (sys.argv[0]))
    sys.exit(1)

script_path = sys.argv[1]

if len(sys.argv) == 3:
    db = sys.argv[2]
else:
    db = ":memory:"

try:
    con = sqlite3.connect(db)
    with con:
        cur = con.cursor()
        with open(script_path,'rb') as f:
            cur.executescript(f.read())
except sqlite3.Error as err:
    print("Error occured: %s" % err)
```

I saved this program as **sqlite_import.py**.
I have a database file named **test.db** and a SQL file **world.sql**.
Now I tried to run program as:

```py
sqlite_import.py test.db world.sql
```

But it shows me error like following:

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Jarvis\OneDrive\Documents\Python\Python Data Visualization Cookbook, 2E\2 Knowing Your Data\sqlite_import.py", line 21, in <module>
    cur.executescript(f.read())
ValueError: script argument must be unicode.
```

Help me to fix this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You opened the script file as *binary*:

```
with open(script_path,'rb') as f:
```

This produces a `b'...'` bytes value, not a Unicode `str` object. Remove the `b`, and perhaps add an `encoding` argument to specific what codec to use to decode the data with.

Comment: Tried various codecs like **utf-8**, **cp037**, **cp437** and **ascii** too. but none of this helped. While using **utf-8**: `'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xb9 in position 27: invalid start byte`. While using **cp037**: `Error occured: near "ëé": syntax error`. While using **cp437**: `Error occured: near "SQLite": syntax error`. **Now what?**

Comment: **Note:** If you run this program using **Python 2.x**, it will run **without any errors**.

Comment: @Harshil: Yes, that's because Python 2 is bytestrings all the way. In Python 3, you have to provide a Unicode string. You'll have to find the right encoding for that file, and I can't tell you that encoding. Clearly the codecs you used are not it.